# DataSet Insert into tables

Tags: c#, sql, insert, dataset

Is that possible to insert into SQL with `DataSet` input ?

I have created my `DataSet` like this :

```
SqlCommand comm_SelectAll = new SqlCommand(sql_SelectAll, connectionWrapper.conn);
comm_SelectAll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NO_CLIENT", IdClient);

if (Anne != "") 
       comm_SelectAll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE_PERIMER", Anne);

SqlDataAdapter adapt_SelectAll = new SqlDataAdapter();
adapt_SelectAll.SelectCommand = comm_SelectAll;

DataSet dSet_SelectAll = new DataSet();
adapt_SelectAll.Fill(dSet_SelectAll);
dSet_SelectAll.Dispose();
adapt_SelectAll.Dispose();
```

Now I want to insert data into SQL table xx, how can I do that ?

Thanks you in advance

Comment: http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-ADONET-Insert-Record-Using-Dataset and a **great many** more basic ADO.NET DataSet tutorials.... Google is your friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this ...with out using dataset

```
public static string BuildSqlNativeConnStr(string server, string database)
{
  return string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;", server, database);
}
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  const string query = "Insert Into Employees (RepNumber, HireDate) Values (@RepNumber, @HireDate)";
  string connStr = BuildSqlNativeConnStr("apex2006sql", "Leather");

  try
  {
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
      conn.Open();
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
      {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RepNumber", 50));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HireDate", DateTime.Today));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    }
  }
  catch (SqlException)
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
  }
}
```